# How can I put the stdout into a text in Tkinter, python?

Tags: python, button, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I use a button to callback a function foo:

```
def foo(value):
  print value 
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
remap_button = Tk.Button(root, text = 'Remap', command = lambda: foo(val))
```

How can I print the output of foo into a text in Tkinter,python?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you're looking for the function to add stuff to a Text widget:

```
def foo(value):
    text.insert(END, value)
```

If you're trying use `print` and want to *redirect* its output from stdout to a widget, well, that's not how it works :P

Comment: Well, you can reset `sys.stdout` to be a StringIO buffer and then read that back into a text widget ... But, It's probably not the cleanest solution.